# Convert to custom class using GSON and Generics with Kotlin in XPLPC project

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, gson

I have a problem that appear be simple, but im making something wrong.

How i can convert from a generic class with reified using GSON and Kotlin in my project called XPLPC?

The error is here:
https://github.com/xplpc/xplpc/actions/runs/3395808126/jobs/5646151499#step:9:503

```
com.xplpc.library.TodoTest > singleItem[test(AVD) - 12] FAILED 
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.xplpc.library.TodoTest$Todo
    at com.xplpc.library.TodoTest.singleItem(TodoTest.kt:44)
```

It don't understand that i want convert to Todo class instead of LinkedTreeMap.

The code is here:
https://github.com/xplpc/xplpc/blob/main/kotlin/lib/library/src/main/java/com/xplpc/serializer/JsonSerializer.kt#L66-L79

And the code is called by this function:
https://github.com/xplpc/xplpc/blob/main/kotlin/lib/library/src/main/java/com/xplpc/client/RemoteClient.kt#L14-L27

Basically the code is:

```
// Part 1
object RemoteClient {
    inline fun <reified T> call(request: Request, defValue: T? = null): T? {
        try {
            val data = PlatformProxy.call(request.data)
            println(data)
            return XPLPC.config.serializer.decodeFunctionReturnValue<T>(data)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(
                Constants.LOG_GROUP,
                "[RemoteClient : call] Error when try to decode return value: ${e.message}"
            )
        }

        return defValue
    }

    inline fun <reified T> callAsync(request: Request, defValue: T? = null): Deferred<T?> {
        return CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
            return@async call<T>(request, defValue)
        }
    }
}

// Part 2
override fun <T> decodeFunctionReturnValue(data: String): T? {
    try {
        val type = object : TypeToken<JsonFunctionReturnValueData<T>>() {}.type
        val gson = createGson()
        return gson.fromJson<JsonFunctionReturnValueData<T>>(data, type).r
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(
            Constants.LOG_GROUP,
            "[JsonSerializer : decodeFunctionReturnValue] Error when parse json: ${e.message}"
        )
    }

    return null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that for your `decodeFunctionReturnValue` function the type parameter `T` is not `reified`. Therefore at runtime the `TypeToken` you are creating is actually `TypeToken<JsonFunctionReturnValueData<Object>>`. When deserializing `Object`, Gson creates based on the JSON data standard objects, for a JSON object that is a Java `Map` (and Gson's internal implementation is `LinkedTreeMap`).

So if possible the solution would be to make the type parameter `T` here `reified` as well. If that is not possible, maybe the type can be passed as separate `TypeToken` parameter to the function.

---

Future Gson versions (> 2.10.1) will throw an exception when a `TypeToken` captures a type variable and will therefore allow you to indentify such issues earlier. The [Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#typetoken-type-variable) contains additional information and workarounds.

Comment: Nice. It can be reified because JsonSerializer inherit from an interface, and interface cant have reified. How i can pass TypeToken as parameter, since JsonFunctionReturnValueData is a class available only for JsonSerializer. Basically, how to make JsonFunctionReturnValueData works with generic and Type?

Comment: @PauloCoutinho, if `JsonFunctionReturnValueData` is only available in that file you could create the type using [`TypeToken.getParameterized`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html#getParameterized(java.lang.reflect.Type,java.lang.reflect.Type...)), for example: `TypeToken.getParameterized(JsonFunctionReturnValueData::class.java, ...)` But you still need to pass its type argument to that call somehow, for example as `TypeToken` and then call `TypeToken.getType()` and pass that as argument to `getParameterized`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you check if it is correct or can be problematic in future? Only a review: https://github.com/xplpc/xplpc/blob/main/kotlin/lib/library/src/main/java/com/xplpc/client/RemoteClient.kt#L17-L18 and https://github.com/xplpc/xplpc/blob/main/kotlin/lib/library/src/main/java/com/xplpc/serializer/JsonSerializer.kt#L58-L70

Comment: @PauloCoutinho, I only had a short look at it, but to me that looks good.